# Is this the correct way to send formData to an API with an image file in react native expo

Tags: react-native, axios

In `react native expo` I am trying to send an image and some image file using a `formData`, I used `expo-image-picker` for image upload, but when I send I get a 500 error

I tried putting the image uri as I was uploading but the app crashes right away, Every time when I send I mostly get a `connection error` or an `error 500`. But if I send the image uri
This is my code for picking the image

```js
   const pickImageAsync = async () => {
    let result = await ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync({
      allowsEditing: true,
      quality: 1,
    });

    if (!result.canceled) {
      setImage(result);
      setImageUri(image.assets[0].uri)
    } else {
      alert('You did not select any image.');
    }
  };
```

**And this is my code for uploading**

```js
   formData.append("profilePicture", {
     name: new Date() + "_picture",
     uri: imageUri,
     type: "image/jpeg",
   });

   await axios({
     method: "PATCH",
     url: `{{url}}`,
     headers: {
       "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data",
       Accept: "application/json",
       Authorization: `Bearer ${authToken}`,
     },
     data: formData,  
   })
```

Comment: Take a look on your server, 500 refers to internal server error.